# How to fill the <a> tag to fill the parent div inside container

Tags: html, css, electron

I started a new electron project(angulat 9 : using scss), currently stuck at making custom title bar. Here is my code:

app.component.html

```html
<div class="container">
  <app-titlebar></app-titlebar>

  <div id="router_outlet">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

titlebar.component.html

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0 ;
  padding: 0 ;
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100% ;
}



.titlebar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black ; /* for reference*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 3rem;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.window-button,
.back-button {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: lighter;
  -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}

.window-button {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.back-button {
  padding-left: 17px;
  padding-right: 17px;
}

#restore {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.window,
.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.normal:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.danger:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="titlebar">
  <div class="navigation">
    <a class="back-button normal material-icons">arrow_back</a>
    <span class="apptitle">Electron-App</span>
  </div>
  <div class="window">
    <a class="window-button normal material-icons">remove</a>
    <a *ngIf="showMaximizeButton ; else showRestore" class="window-button normal material-icons">crop_square</a>
    <!-- <ng-template #showRestore>
      <a class="window-button normal material-icons" id="restore">flip_to_front</a>
    </ng-template> -->
    <a class="window-button danger material-icons">clear</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is how to fill these `<a>` tag entirely to their parent div element height so that on hovering these link the background area filled fully to the `.titlebar` height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set their height to full and make them flex too to allow vertical positioning of their content (they are already set to `inline-block`:

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0 ;
  padding: 0 ;
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100% ;
}

.titlebar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black ; /* for reference*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 3rem;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.window-button,
.back-button {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: lighter;
  -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-flex !important;
  align-items: center;
}

.window-button {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.back-button {
  padding-left: 17px;
  padding-right: 17px;
}

#restore {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.window,
.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.normal:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.danger:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="titlebar">
  <div class="navigation">
    <a class="back-button normal material-icons">arrow_back</a>
    <span class="apptitle">Electron-App</span>
  </div>
  <div class="window">
    <a class="window-button normal material-icons">remove</a>
    <a *ngIf="showMaximizeButton ; else showRestore" class="window-button normal material-icons">crop_square</a>
    <!-- <ng-template #showRestore>
      <a class="window-button normal material-icons" id="restore">flip_to_front</a>
    </ng-template> -->
    <a class="window-button danger material-icons">clear</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: spent few days to solve this problem, thanks @LucasFlint

Answer (score 1):

You could make the anchor tags use `display: flex`:

```css
.titlebar a,
.window a {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here's the working snippet:

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0 ;
  padding: 0 ;
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100% ;
}

.titlebar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black ; /* for reference*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 3rem;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.titlebar a,
.window a {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.window-button,
.back-button {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: lighter;
  -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}

.window-button {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.back-button {
  padding-left: 17px;
  padding-right: 17px;
}

#restore {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.window,
.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.normal:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.danger:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="titlebar">
  <div class="navigation">
    <a class="back-button normal material-icons">arrow_back</a>
    <span class="apptitle">Electron-App</span>
  </div>
  <div class="window">
    <a class="window-button normal material-icons">remove</a>
    <a *ngIf="showMaximizeButton ; else showRestore" class="window-button normal material-icons">crop_square</a>
    <!-- <ng-template #showRestore>
      <a class="window-button normal material-icons" id="restore">flip_to_front</a>
    </ng-template> -->
    <a class="window-button danger material-icons">clear</a>
  </div>
</div>
```